# parameter interval deprecated in animate() since version 4.3.0 flutter package flutter_animate

Tags: flutter

Before version 4.3.0 we could specify interval (delay between animations) like this:

tabInfoItems = tabInfoItems
.animate(**interval**: 400.ms)
.fadeIn(duration: 1400.ms, delay: 300.ms)

but it is no more available.
How to do please?